# How to use useCallback with currying function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `useCallback` to memo my callback function but it doesn't seem to work with currying function, my `PhotoItem` component always re-render when `MyListPhoto` re-render although I wrapping my PhotoItem in React.memo(). Because `handleDelete` function is a currying function, is there any way to use with useCallback ?

```
const MyListPhoto = () => {
   ...other state...
   const { delete } = useDeletePhoto();

   // always create new function when component re-render
   const handleDelete = useCallback((index) => (photoId) => {
      delete(photoId, index)
   }, []);

   return (
     <ul>
        {photos.map((photo, index) => (
           <PhotoItem
              key={photo.id}
              photo={photo}
              onDelete={handleDelete(index)}
           />
        ))}
     </ul>
   )
}
```

PhotoItem component:

```
const PhotoItem = React.memo(({ photo, onDelete }) => {
    console.log('re-render');

    return (
      ...
    )
})
```

Comment: Show how you wrap it using `React.memo`

Comment: @Konrad I updated my question. Help me check it

Comment: @Konrad useCallback not work with currying function, that right?

Comment: You create a new function every time so it can't work

Comment: `handleDelete` will always be the same function on each render, contrary to what you say - the issue though is that calling it on each render to get `handleDelete(index)` is indeed a new function reference each time it's done. That's actually nothing to do with `useCallback`, or currying, any time you define an event handler, or other prop function, as the result of a function call, this is going to happen.

Comment: What is `photoId`? Do you even **need** to pass the `index` to `delete`?

Comment: @Bergi yes, I need pass both `index` and `photoId` to delete

Comment: @Epple But **why**? The id should be sufficient. Removing the `index` parameter would save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to memoize each function

```
const MyListPhoto = () => {
  // ...other state...
  const { del } = useDeletePhoto();

  const deleteHandlers = useMemo(() => {
    return photos.map((photo, index) => (photoId) => del(photoId, index));
  }, [photos]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {photos.map((photo, index) => (
        <PhotoItem
          key={photo.id}
          photo={photo}
          onDelete={deleteHandlers[index]}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Konrad, I have a question, why can't we use useCallback in this case?

Comment: Because `useCallback` returns one function, but you want as many  functions as `photos.length`

Comment: thanks for your great answer, it's easy to understand.

Comment: Actually it's sufficient to use `photos.length` as the dependency, since the functions actually do not depend on the `photo` value itself. But it will still re-render all `<PhotoItem>`s when the array (length) changes.

Comment: @Bergi I will refer to another way, it seems that the way I am implementing is really an inefficient way

Comment: To be honest this is a good idea and I upvoted but I think there is not need to memorise an array with n functions especially when n is big, in fact we don't need to memorize anything but the op want to memorise, so memorising only one function is enough isn't? it looks more secure your implementation but since you end by passing the index or its coressponding function to each child so we return to the same point storing one is enough. hope you get my point ^^

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I didn't get the point! Why do you need to memorize the function?
how about this:

```
...
return <ul>
        {photos.map((photo, index) => (
           <PhotoItem key={photo.id} photo={photo} onDelete={() => delete(photo.id, index)}  />
     </ul>
   )
```

Comment: It will rerender every `PhotoItem` component every time the state changes

Comment: it is because you are creating a new `PhotoItem` in the map function and it has not any other choice

Comment: it's normal to list refresh after any change

Comment: It's because props change. OP is using `React.memo` to prevent that, but props can't change

Comment: let see what I am doing, my intention is keep `PhotoItem`s in `map` loop not re-render by memoized `onDelete` prop. Why do that? Because every time `MyListPhoto` re-render, if I am not use `useCallback`, it leads to `onDelete` create new function even if `onDelete` callback not trigger, so React will say: "Oh, `onDelete` prop has changed. I will re-render your component".

Comment: Hi @ParsaS, are u get my point ?

Comment: I know what you are doing! I see! but I don't know why you use that!
the `useDeletePhoto` looks like a custom hook so you can handle this memorization or other state management there.
I think you are looking to the wrong place to solve the problem.
my suggestion: don't use `useCallback` and `useMemo`  let `MyListPhoto` handle its data and hide `PhotoItem` instead of delete (send delete request to server). it will avoid to extra render