# How to apply useCallback inside loops?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm trying to understand `memo` and `useCallback` and I've made this minimal example:

```
import { memo, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Text, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";

const Item = memo(({ isSelected, index, onClicked }) => {
  return (<TouchableOpacity onPress={onClicked}>
    <Text style={{ backgroundColor: (isSelected ? "red" : "transparent"), paddingVertical: 10 }}>{index}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>)

})


export default function App() {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(10)

  let items = []
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++)

    items.push(
      <Item
        key={i}
        index={i}
        isSelected={selected == i}
        onClicked={useCallback(() => setSelected(i), [])}

      />
    )

  return (<SafeAreaView>
    <Button title="Change to 5" onPress={() => { setCount(5); setSelected(1) }} />

    {items}

  </SafeAreaView>)
}
```

This works fine until I change the `count` by clicking on `Button`

and It gives the error:

> Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

Don't I have to use `useCallback()` so that the `<Item>` don't get re rendered due to a "new function" (onClicked) being passed in as props every time?

How do I avoid re rendering every time a new item is selected?

---

**Edit**

Based on Konrad's comment I utilized `useMemo` like this:

```js
import { memo, useCallback, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Text, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";

const Item = memo(({ isSelected, index, onClicked }) => {

  return (<TouchableOpacity onPress={onClicked}>
    <Text style={{ backgroundColor: (isSelected ? "red" : "transparent"), paddingVertical: 10 }}>{index}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>)

})


export default function App() {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(10)

  const func_arr = useMemo(() => {

    let arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) // loop 1
      arr.push(() => setSelected(i))

    return arr

  },[count])

  let items = []
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) // loop 2

    items.push(
      <Item
        key={i}
        index={i}
        isSelected={selected == i}
        onClicked={func_arr[i]} // How do I pass arguments to this?

      />
    )

  return (<SafeAreaView>
    <Button title="Change to 5" onPress={() => { setCount(5); setSelected(1) }} />

    {items}

  </SafeAreaView>)
}
```

But this raises more questions then it solves:

1. How do I avoid using 2 loops? One for the `<Item>` & the other for `useMemo`
2. How do I pass arguments to `func_arr[i]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use useCallback with currying function in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748174/how-to-use-usecallback-with-currying-function-in-react)

Comment: @Konrad well not exactly, I used your solution from that question but it brings up other problems, could you please see the edit?

Comment: You don't need `useCallback` here.

Comment: Maybe this will help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590082/how-to-prevent-re-rendering-of-components-that-have-not-changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things here, reacts expects you to allways use the same hooks, hooks should not be conditionally used, nor used inside a loop that can change.

In your case, when you change the value of "count", you will use "useCallback" one less time, that's why you get that error message.

The good news is your workaround is actually correct, let me explain, the "useCallback" hook is used to prevent Reat to re-compiling the function everytime the component gets updated.

That being said, what you want to do is define a function that is going to always be the same, in your case:

```
(index) => { setSelected(index) }
```

That function will allways behave the same, so it does not need to be built over and over. Then, you use useCallback to be able to use that function everywhere you need it.

**Edited to add example based on comment:**

Just to clarify, in your example I probably wouldn't use any of these hooks, because is not that expensive to re render things, but I understand this is an example and you're trying to learn how to use them. So, let met show you what I would do to use both hooks in this example:

```js
import { memo, useCallback, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Text, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(10)
  
  // We use useCallback to save this function and stop re-building it every time the component updates
  const callbackFunction = useCallback((index) => setSelected(i), [])
  // Since we have callbackFunction and we can pass a parameter, we remover the first loop
  
  // If you don't want to pass all those parameters (which is pretty usual if you are adding a child component), 
  // you can add another useCallback it inside the component like this:
  const getMemoizedItemComponent = useCallback((index) => {
    const isSelected = index === selected
    
    return (<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => callbackFunction(index)}>
      <Text style={{ backgroundColor: (isSelected ? "red" : "transparent"), paddingVertical: 10 }}>{index}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>)
  }, [callbackFunction])

  let items = []
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) // loop 2

    items.push(
      getMemoizedItemComponent(i)
    )

  return (<SafeAreaView>
    <Button title="Change to 5" onPress={() => { setCount(5); setSelected(1) }} />

    {items}

  </SafeAreaView>)
}
```

Just one more comment here, I don't think needing to pass those 3 params to "Item" is a big deal. There are ways to make it a little better (like useContext) but it won't help here.
Usually if you have a component rendering child components based on a list, you'll end up passing a bunch of props to each one of them.

Comment: Insightful, but when I said it's a workaround instead of a solution I meant that because I'll still have to pass `index` ( and other arguments I might require) as props and "reassemble" the function inside `<Item>` which seems like a headache when it would be much simpler to pass an already defined function as a prop

Comment: I see what you're saying. Give me a minute, I'll update my answer with what I'd do

Comment: I'm a little confused, why `useCallback` for `getMemoizedItemComponent` ? I thought `useMemo()` or `React.memo` was used to wrap components

Comment: You're 100% right, usually you would go with useMemo for components BUT, in this case I wanted to give you an option to avoid passing all the parameters to the component, since you weren't happy with it and useCallback allowed me that.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a solution (more of a workaround) but it's possible to pass the `useCallback` function itself as such:

```
import { memo, useCallback, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Text, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";

const Item = memo(({ isSelected, index, onClicked }) => {

  console.log("Render Item", index)

  return (<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onClicked(index)}>
    <Text style={{ backgroundColor: (isSelected ? "red" : "transparent"), paddingVertical: 10 }}>{index}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>)

})


export default function App() {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(10)

  const changeSelected = useCallback((index) => {
    setSelected(index)
  }, [])


  let items = []
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    items.push(
      <Item
        key={i}
        index={i}
        isSelected={selected == i}
        onClicked={changeSelected}

      />
    )
  }

  return (<SafeAreaView>
    <Button title="Change to 5" onPress={() => { setCount(5); setSelected(1) }} />

    {items}

  </SafeAreaView>)
}
```